# Rails - Display a different form for the same action based on the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple Client model with some fields and a basic form. The url to access it is `/clients/new`, that leads to `clients#new` method. What I need to do is create a new route to resellers, that will lead to the same method and the same form, but with some new fields, like the reseller's name.

Example: url `/reseller/clients/new` leads to the method `clients#new` and display a new cell with new inputs for the `new` form.

I created a method that checks the url and sets a session if the route has `"reseller"` in it, so my cell can handle if the new fields will be displayed or not. But this is leading me to problems regarding model validations, since if the new fields are displayed in the view, theire presence is `true`. I would have to access my sessions inside the model in order to create a proper validation, and that does not sound as the right path.

I wonder how can I achieve my goal within a proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would recommend you to split it up in different routes and controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

For this I created a new model called `Reseller`. With that, the model `Client` has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reseller`. This way I can render the form in my cell for the `Reseller` model and set all the fields inside it with `:presence => true`, with no need of a conditional statement. If the url has `"reseller"`, the cell will render the form and the validation will happen.